# Navbar using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, i have set up a Navbar and it is responsive too but to a certain screen size. After that it won't resize down. I think the media query kicks in here but i can't work my way around. What i am trying to achieve is that once screen goes down too much then each item should stack up one below the other.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.border {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 0.1;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 0.1;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 0.1;
}

.box-4 {
  flex: 3;
  text-align: right;
}

.box-5 {
  flex: 0.1;
}

h4 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1 border">
    <h4>Home</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2 border">
    <h4>About</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-3 border">
    <h4>Contact</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-4 border">
    <h4>Login</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-5 border">
    <h4>Signup</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using flex, this should do the trick:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 356px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}
```

Comment: let me try this out

Answer (score 0):

- first add `flex-wrap` property in the large screens like this:

  .container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
- then add media query on a certain break point for example 400 px or 320 px like this:

  @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .container {
  flex-direction: column;
  }
  }